# How do I compile and run a Rust file on save using entr?

Tags: shell, rust

How do I use [entr](http://eradman.com/entrproject/) to automatically compile and run a test Rust file on every save? I tried

```
ls test.rs | entr -c "rustc test.rs && ./test"
```

But it gives the error:

```
entr: exec rustc test.rs && ./test: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `-s` argument, which uses your shell to evaluate the command:

> ```
> -s  Evaluate the first argument using the
>     interpreter specified by the SHELL
>     environment variable.  When this flag
>     is set, the name of the shell and exit
>     code is printed after each invocation.
> ```

The correct command is:

```sh
ls test.rs | entr -cs "rustc test.rs && ./test"
```

As a bonus, it also prints the exit code for each invocation!

```
Hello World!
zsh returned exit code 0
```

Similarly for cargo, on any rust file change saved under `src` directory:

```sh
ls src/**/*.rs | entr -cs "cargo run"
```